# Members only site - still need the lost password page accessible

Tags: functions, login

My site requires login before viewing any page and it works great:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) 
{auth_redirect();
}}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

But obviously this means the link to the lost-password page just redirects back to the login page. I've tried changing it to:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in() || (!ispage('lost-password') ))
{auth_redirect();
}}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

But it has the same problem, and when I tried to use wp_lostpassword_url it broke completely.

How can I restrict access to everything other than the lost-password page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your if statement is incorrect it should be an AND (`&&`) not OR

so try

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'lost-password' ) ) {
```

**EDIT**

Try using `$object = get_queried_object()` for checking the post slug

```
$object = get_queried_object();
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( ! $object || 'my-account' !== $object->post_name ) ) {
  // ...
```

**EDIT 2** The page slug was wrong so updated in the second example

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that and I'm afraid it has the same problem. It redirects to http://domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fmy-account%2Flost-password&reauth=1

Comment: @Lyall I have updated my answer with a different solution which uses get_queried_object instead, let me know if that works :)

Comment: Close! The page loads but it has an error at the top of the page - Warning: Use of undefined constant is_user_logged_in - assumed 'is_user_logged_in' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /homepages/45/d622530085/htdocs/xxxx/domain/wp-content/themes/exoplanet/functions.php on line 288

Comment: (I will move this to the child theme functions later today)

Comment: @Lyall that was meant to be a function call, my bad I'll update it

Comment: Thanks for your help - now it's redirecting to http://domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fmy-account%2Flost-password&reauth=1 again

Comment: @Lyall in your second example I noticed, you have an extra `{` in front of the `auth_redirect` function call, is that there in your actual code?

In addition to this, is `lost-password` the actual slug for the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86766/discussion-between-jrmd-and-lyall).